# Displaying countries using country_select gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, country

I am trying to implement the country_select gem (gem 'country_select','~> 2.1.0') in a Rails 4 app without success. This is the code in my form. I have tried several permutations of this from similar questions on stack without success. I don't understand why I am getting the error -

"undefined method `input' for ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fafb5878c48>"

Bear in mind that I am a Rails beginner.

```
    <%= form_for(@user, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :country %><br>
    <%= f.input :country, as: :country %>

    <%= f.submit "Update my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

I have also tried

```
    <%= f.label :country %>
    <%= f.country_select :country  %>
```

from the documentation. 'country' is one of my user attributes.

Any guidance would be welcome on the newbie problem.

Comment: add :country to Users strong parameters

Answer (score 3):

I have just spent an hour on the same problem and am annoyed at the brevity of the github documentation. Nevertheless, this worked for me and it sounds like what you need:

```
<%= f.country_select(:country, {selected: @user.country}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```

I couldn't get the second parameter (see https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) to work - it gave me an error every time I tried to add anything else before the {selected...}.

Comment: Hi MSC. I tried your suggestion in my code (using simple form, country_select and countries gems), bug get this error: undefined local variable or method `country_code' for #<Address:0x007ff8ef158e58>

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= f.country_select :country, {priority_countries: ["SG", "US"], include_blank: "select country"}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

This worked for me, the first `:country` is an attribute of `user`, all the options of `country_select` gem will come as the next parameter and the last param will take the class name and other format features.

If the param contains a single field it can be passed with or without brackets.